# Expectation value in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, statistics

[image]
In Griffiths's introduction to quantum mechanics, there is an equation that gives a general method of calculating the expectation value of some quantity. First, I cannot understand how the parentheses are used (especially in the generalized equation where the equation contains x and partial derivative for x). Furthermore, I cannot understand how equation 1.36 is derived. Can somebody help? (As long as the parentheses are concerned is there any math convention regarding them that implies a specific operation?). The equation I am talking about is shown in the screenshot. In addition to that what would be the expectation value of angular momentum which is a vector quantity?

Comment: Parentheses are used for $Q$ because it is a function of two variables. Also, expectations of vector quantities are taken component-wise.

Comment: But what exactly does it mean in the final equation where there are contained in the parenthesis both the x component and the partial derivative with respect to x? In the example of the momentum that is shown I understood that using the parenthesis for the derivative was a new way of expressing the differantiation of Ψ with respect to x.In the final equation he is using Q and obviously the parenthesis is refering to Q but I cannot understand what operation does this command us to do.

Comment: Stuff like this assumes that you can write $Q(x, p)$ as a Taylor expansion. Then you just change powers of $p^n$ to n-th derivatives. Then the only thing to watch out for is that a term like $px$ does not evaluate to $1$ but $1 + \partial_x$ because you have to remember that there's something to the right on which the operator is designed to act.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have some operator, $\hat{Q}$ which has eigenvalues given by

\begin{equation}
\hat{Q}|\phi_{q}\rangle = q|\phi_{q}\rangle
\end{equation}

Let's say that you have some quantum state, $|\psi\rangle$ and, because you're interested in the operator $\hat{Q}$, you decide to express this state in terms of the eigenkets of $\hat{Q}$ such that

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \sum_{q}c_{q}|\phi_{q}\rangle
\end{equation}

where the coefficients $c_{q} = \langle \phi_{q}|\psi\rangle$ and $\sum_{q} |c_{q}|^{2} = 1$. We can interpret $|c_{q}|^{2}$ as the probability that we measure $|\psi\rangle$ in the state $|\phi_{q}\rangle$. Expectation values are the average value of $q$ we would expect to measure for a quantum state $|\psi\rangle$.The expectation value is given as

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle\hat{Q}\rangle &= \langle \psi |\hat{Q}|\psi\rangle \\
&= \sum_{q, q^{\prime}} c_{q^{\prime}}^{*}c_{q}\langle\phi_{q^{\prime}}|\hat{Q}|\phi_{q}\rangle \\
&= \sum_{q, q^{\prime}} c_{q^{\prime}}^{*}c_{q} q \langle\phi_{q^{\prime}}|\phi_{q}\rangle \\
&= \sum_{q, q^{\prime}} c_{q^{\prime}}^{*}c_{q} q  \delta_{q, q^{\prime}} \\
&= \sum_{q} q |c_{q}|^{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

which is indeed, the average value we measure for $\hat{Q}$.

Let's say $\hat{Q}$ is actually a function of the position and momentum operators, $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$. In the position basis, the momentum operator is given as

\begin{equation}
\hat{p} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\end{equation}

and therefore

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle \hat{Q} \rangle &= \langle \psi | \hat{Q} | \psi \rangle \\
&= \int \left( \psi^{*}(x) Q\left(x, -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \psi(x) \right) \text{d}x
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Why does $\hat Q$ have to be limited to sums of position and momentum operators? It can be any function of these operators, right?

Comment: Of course, as long as $\hat{Q}$ is Hermitian then it can be a function of any arbitrary operators.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused as to why you only mention a sum.